# How can I use a .NET 2.0 dll in classic ASP?

Tags: dll, asp-classic, .net-2.0

I have a c# .NET DLL compiled against the .NET 2.0 framework.

A customer uses classic ASP but needs the functionality of the .NET DLL. Is there a way for them to use the DLL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to consume the .NET dll as a [COM callable wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx).
This generally involves marking it as COM-visible (via attributes), and registering it as a COM component (regasm?).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439(VS.80).aspx) for more.

The server will need the .NET framework, of course.

Comment: Stuff that for a game of soldiers! Think I'll give it a miss.

Comment: @Tim - It's pretty straightforward in all honesty.

Answer (score 0):

i think exposing it to COM is your only option (might be wrong)